# Jenkins can not clone Git repository

Tags: java, git, jenkins, gitlab

I am using GitLab and I can't cloned Git repository in Jenkins when I paste it I get this error 
[image]

Can anybody help me please

Edit 1: to answer to first answer 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the "\git.exe" at the end of "Path to Git executable".

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Comment: I think Joseph is saying that you need to update you config to c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe